# turning off run-time check in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have an application developed in linux(fedora6-13) it uses MITK, ITK, VTK, QT3. 
I installed VS2008 and also MITK, ITK, VTK, QT3. When i run the application it works fine however after every action i make (clicking on button, changig state of a slider) i get the following error: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'variablename' was corrupted. here i can hit continue and the app keeps on working just fine.

Is there a way to disable this runtime-check?

Thank You

Zoli

Comment: Why would you want to mitigate the symptom of an obviously quite major problem? Try to find / fix the cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That runtime check tells you that you have a bug - don't turn off the check, fix the bug.

If you want to have random behavior, aka not fix the bug, then you *can* disable the check in project properties: `C++/Code Generation/Basic Runtime Checks`. Be aware that this will lead to all sorts of weird problems - you won't be overwriting just the data VS uses to detect such overflows, you'll be overwriting data *your app* uses.

I'd suggest you post the relevant code here on SO - you'll get help fixing the problem instead of hiding it.

Comment: it stopped giving those errors! thank you! I don't think the code is the problem. it's been checked with coverity,etc. and there are no leaks or memory handling problems. i think it's only because it was developed under a different oerating system, c/c++ complier and i dont eve know what else. it worked really stabil under fedora. plus i can't post it here because it against a tons of rules and its really long. Bottomline is: Thank You very much for your help!

Comment: @Zoltan Varadi: Remember what I said above when you start getting strange bugs.

Comment: I didn't have any RTC errors; I just wanted to turn on /O2 optimization so I could see TCO in action in a tiny program with recursion. Other sources say to turn off RTC, but they don't say where that option is in VS, so this helped.

Comment: I don't see a way to remove RTC from this, I can change it to RTCs or RTCu but not remove it. Similar to TigerhawkT3 I'm trying to run a fully tested program with optimizations

Comment: lol, you have to actually delete it out of the "text box" rather than there being a drop-down option for it

Comment: Who tells you that it's a bug? Not everyone needs babysitting. Many people know what they are doing.